# Docker run with variable volume bindings

Tags: docker, powershell

I'm looking for a Solution to add volume bindings based on a list when running docker run.

But keep getting errors, is there a Solution to allow a variable amount of volume mappings?

I've tried PowerShell splatting e.g.

```
$VolumeList = @{}
$VolumeList += @{v = "C:\certs:C:\certs"}
$VolumeList += @{v = "C:\temp:C:\temp"}
$VolumeList += @{v = "C:\share:C:\share"}
```

But I'm running in this error:

```
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'v'  Key being added: 'v'
At line:3 char:1

+ $VolumeList += @{v = "C:\\temp"}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
  
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I also tried to do it with just a String e.g.

```
$VolumeList = '-v "C:\certs:C:\certs" -v "C:\temp:C:\temp" -v "C:\share:C:\share"'
docker run `
    -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" `
    -e "ACCEPT_OUTDATED=Y" `
    -e "USESSL=N" `
    --name "$publishContainerName" `
    --network updateNet `
    @VolumeList `
```

But then I'm running into a format error.

Comment: "But then I'm running into a format error." - are you expecting us to telepathically read it off your screen? :)

Comment: The line of code with `@{}` is creating hash table  and you cannot put two items with same key into the hash.  Replace the curly brackets with parenthesis.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen good point 
docker : docker: invalid reference format.
At C:\agent_nsys-update\_work\1\newsystem_ps_tools\Update-ContainerImages.ps1:200 char:17
+                 docker run `
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (docker: invalid reference format.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError